# Having issues with onclick() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, onclick, double

I got a check box - when I check it, it prints out a drop down list, but when I uncheck it, the drop down list doesn't disappear. On the second click after unchecking it (i.e. third click in total) the *entire* page disappears; when I just want the drop down list to disappear and the check box to remain.

I've got the code below.

```
<?php 
include('dbcategory.php');

?>
<script type="text/javascript">


var app = true;



function rFields1(elm){
    if (app == false){

var tra = elm.parentNode.parentNode;
tra.remove();

    }
    app = true;
}

function addFields1(){
    if(app == true){    
    var container = document.getElementById("container1");
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    table.border=1; 
    table.cellspacing=0;     
    table.id ="education";
    table.name = "education[]";     
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.valign = "top";

    var slct = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
    slct.id = "institution";
    slct.name = "institution[]";
    //some php code that is generating js code
    <?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM levels ORDER BY id asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[level]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[level]';\r\n");
        echo("slct.appendChild(opt);");
    }
    ?>

    slct.value='<?php echo $_GET['id2']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
    container.appendChild(slct);//? how do I fix this up
        //      select1.appendChild(option);
    td1.appendChild(slct);
    tr.appendChild(td1);




    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));


    table.appendChild(tr);  
    container.appendChild(table);   
    app = false;
    }

    else {
    colour.onclick=function(){
    rFields1(this);};   
        //  app = true;
    }
    }

</script>
<form id="myform" action="" align="center" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="div2">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>

<input type="hidden" id="idz" name="idz">



<br><H2 align="center">EDUCATION</H2><br>
<div id="container1">
<table border="1" id="education" name="education[]" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">

<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<input name="colour" id="colour" type="checkbox" onclick="addFields1()" />
<a href="#" type="hidden" id="Remove" name="Remove" onclick="rFields1(this)"></a>


</table>

</div>


</table>


</form>
<br>
```

[Checkbox Unchecked By Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkvt5.jpg)

[Checked Checkbox printing out the dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8DZw.jpg)

[Checkbox Unchecked - no change or effect](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2zf0u9f.jpg)

[Second time the newly unchecked checkbox checked results in a Blank Screen](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wrjapw&s=9#.VugVXHr0dSk)

Comment: I'd suggest you indent your code better and make sure those links are correctly using markdown (which they are currently not). Otherwise it's unlikely anyone will want to read through poorly indented code.

Comment: can u not just copy and paste the code i inserted?

Comment: @BenStein The expectation isn't that everyone who looks at this is going to copy your code and try to figure it out.  If its properly formatted, more people can take a look and see if something is amiss from a glance as opposed to digging through the code.  Also it just makes everything more organized for anyone using this question in the future.

Comment: @BenStein that's your code then you have to present it better. People here can do this but if you are asking a question then you should do it instead of asking a answer provider. If you don't know how to do it? Plz take a tour in the help center. Good luck. ;)

Comment: ok i'll fix it up then

Comment: i just fixed it up right now...hopefully ya'all like it now :D

Comment: @BenStein The code still looks poorly indented.

Comment: well that's the best i could do...hope it helps...its not complicated stuff though...i can't figure out why it ain't going through...

Comment: is it required that i re-indent it again?

Comment: i fixed it up again...the 2nd time...any more critiques?

Comment: @BenStein That looks better.  The HTML could be cleaned up a little more but it's definitely more readable now.

Comment: thanks...hopefully this issue is solved...

Comment: thanks a million bud! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you click your checkbox, it creates the dropdown. The second click executes the following:

```
colour.onclick=function(){
rFields1(this);};
```

I'm not sure why that does not crash, as colour was not defined anywhere, but let's assume it doesn't. It will only set the onclick function but will not execute it. So the second click does not show any changes. The third click will then remove the parents parent of your checkbox, which basically deletes everything you see.

I guess you have to write something like

```
document.getElementById("education").remove();
app = true;
```

in your else case and get rid of rFields1.